# SQL Server - Avoid calling function twice

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the SQL toy example below, `SUM()` is called twice. Is there any trick to do the computation of a function just once? The reason behind this is that calling twice may be less efficient.

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp(Id int);
INSERT INTO #Tmp VALUES (1), (2), (-10);
SELECT IIF(SUM(Id) < 0, 0, SUM(Id)) FROM #Tmp;
```

In Python, we have so-called **Assignment Expressions**:

```
if (list_length := len(some_list)) < 0:
    return 0
else:
    return list_length
```

In C#, we have **coalesce operator: ??**

```
var x = callFunctionThatCouldReturnNull() ?? valueIfNull;
```

...at least help us in case of checking null.

Do we have something similar in SQL? One can workaround by assigning to a variable, but then more code to write...

-- Updated --

I need something similar in SQL because of:

- Syntatic sugar: repeating code is boring.
- Potential performance issue: as said in comments, SQL Compiler may be intelligent enough to recognize the function `SUM()` is called twice. But what if we have a very *complex/long query* in `IIF()` (instead of just `SUM()`), is it **always guaranteed** that SQL Compiler also detects that those code snippets are the same, so it saves the result from the 1st call and re-use later?

Comment: The table is scanned and the aggregate is computed only once in your query.

Comment: You're presuming that that SQL is executed as written.  It's not.  SQL is a declarative language; that is, the database engine takes your SQL and generates it's own "execution plan", very much like a smart compiler.  In the formation of that plan the SQL Server's optimisation engine notes that you have two calls to `SUM(id)` and is able to use the result twice without processing the underlying rows twice.  I recommend that you test these cases before assuming they're problems.  Run your query with 1B rows, with and without the double call, and check the execution plans and elapsed times, etc.

Comment: "In C#, we have coalesce operator: ??" In SQL we also have `COALESCE()`

Comment: If you are using Azure SQL database you can just replace the whole thing with `GREATEST(SUM(Id), 0)` - coming to vNext of SQL Server on premise presumably - though no benefit in this case of doing so

Comment: SQL does have `COALESCE` - but `ISNULL(subquery, x)` is more efficient in SQL Server as `COALESCE` would evaluate the subquery twice

Comment: I'm not sure why my question is closed due to "not reproducible or was caused by typos". I tested the sql script, using SQL Server 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some misconceptions that you have about SQL queries.

In general, the expensive part of the query is reading the data, not doing the sum.  This is especially true on trivially small amounts of data.

Second, SQL queries *describe* the result set.  SQL is a *declarative* language, not a *procedural* language.  The optimizer is free to see that there are two `SUM()`s that can be calculated only once.  I'm not so sure that SQL Server does this optimization.

There are some cases where calling functions can be expensive (I don't think `SUM()` on integers is one of those cases).  If this is a concern, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN sum_id < 0 THEN 0 ELSE sum_id END)
FROM (SELECT SUM(Id) as sum_id
      FROM #Tmp t
     ) t;
```

Also note that I replaced the `IIF()` with the standard SQL `CASE` expression.